# How to change twentyseventeen Responsive Navigation Breakpoint

Tags: wordpress, responsive

I am using the twentysenteen wordpress theme. I want to change the Breakpoint of the desktop menu to the responsive menu. 
Is there any way that you can change it a clean way. I only found some fishy Css solutions in the web.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i found a solution a pretty clean solution.
There are two basic things you need to change.

First display the toggle button

```
.js .menu-toggle,
.js .dropdown-toggle {
  display: block;
}
```

and secondly just hide the menu ul

```
.js .main-navigation ul, .js .main-navigation ul ul, .js .main-navigation > div > ul {
 display: none;
}
```

than add some styles like display: block the li